# difference between thread.start() and executor.submit(thread)

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

i am facing a problem regarding the thread. I am having a class which implements runnable, and i can use thread.start() method on that class.
My question is i have one more class `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService` in which i can call executor.submit(thread)..

can anyone please tell me what is the difference between `thread.start()` and `executor.submit(thread)`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The executor.submit method takes a Runnable, not a Thread. The point of executorServices is that they take control over creating and pooling threads so the code calling them doesn't have to.

Answer (score 1):

You should not submit a thread to an executor. First it is simply a waste because the only method that will be called on it is `run()`, and you just need a `Runnable` and don't need a `Thread` for that.

Secondary, while this issue is solved in the latest JDK, it used to be the case that a memory leak problem occurs if you create a lot of `Thread` objects and don't call `.start()` on them.  Basically creating a `Thread` objects allocates some memory that can only be reclaimed after `.start()` was called. Therefore, doing `executor.submit(thread)` is potentially hazardous in earlier JDKs (I think it was only solved in JDK6 or so).

Coming back to your question, executor.submit(thread) is not valid.. It is simply wrong, because an executor uses its own thread to execute the runnable. That's after all the whole point of using a executor. You want to separate task (invocation) and execution. Only if you want to supply the executor (thread), you should be using `Thread`, but it is rare that you need to do so. Generally it is advisable to implement a `Runnable` and use executors to execute it, rather than dealing with `Thread` yourself.